# Display form data from angular on a server using $http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, server

I am using a form in html, using angular, and binding the username and email id of the user.

I wish to display the details of the particular user onto a server page, where in when a user clicks on Submit details on the front end, the data is "binded" and the information is simultaneously shown on the server page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Random title here</title>

<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="mainctrl as ctrl">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<form name="userform" ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
<div class="form-group"> 
<label> Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-ctrl" ng-model="ctrl.user.name">

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label> Email id</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-ctrl" ng-model="user.email">

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>

</form>
</div>
</div>


<script>
var test=angular.module('test',[]);
test.controller('mainctrl',[function($scope,$html){
$scope.user={};
$scope.submit= function () { 
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'test1.java', //No idea what to put here. Help pls.
        data : $scope.user;
    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data)
            {
        console.log("Success");
            });
}
}]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just a sample of code I typed. As a beginner, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. As I understood you want to send data to backend side?

Comment: You will need to put URL to your rest endpoint there. Try inspecting the error in chrome console and see how angular is forming the complete URL. If that's not correct try correcting it.

Comment: @BakhtierGaibulloev Yes. For now, I just want that when an user submits his data, i.e. his username and email id, the data needs to be shown on a server page.

After going through several links, everyone usually gets the data in the $http through GET or POST, and then passes the information to the UI. But here, I wish to do the opposite. Just read the data from the form, and display it on the server page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `controller as` syntax than you should write your function with reference `this`. Your controller snippet would be like

```
angular.module('test',[])
  .controller('mainctrl',[function($scope, $http){
    var cm = this;
    cm.user={};
    cm.submit= function () { 
      $http({
          method : 'POST',
          url : form.attributes['target'], 
          data : cm.user;
      }).success(function(data)
            {
        console.log("Success");
            });
    }
}]);
```

and pass the form element in your `ng-submit` directive. Like

```
<form name="userform" ng-submit="ctrl.submit($element.action)">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up. Would keep this in mind.

Comment: @ShivangKapoor if you find my answer is useful please don't forget to upvote.

Comment: Need to earn +15 more reputation for up voting. :D But will surely do it once I reach that level.

Comment: But could you help me out on how to display the data on to a server page, using the data from the form.

Comment: You should use model `ng-model="ctrl.user.name"` & `ng-model="ctrl.user.email"` and you will get the data in controller under `cm.user` object

Answer (score 0):

I hope my code will be usefull for you!

View:

```
<body ng-controller="UserDataController">
<form ng-submit="sendData(user)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="user.name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="second name" ng-model="user.second_name" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                Save
    </button>
</form >
```

Cotroller:

```
angular.module('httpExample', [])
    .controller('UserDataController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.sendData= function(user) {
            $http.post("/SomeUrl", user).success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);

                $scope.data = data; 
                // now you can write {{data}} at your veiw
                // example {{data.id}}
            });
      }]);
```

Example: get [request](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Comment: Jax-RS/Jersey for now.

Comment: so if you use my code you will send your data to your backend. At backend you should take request with data. Do you have any question yet?